# What's wrong with my Angular filter?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have an array of objects and I want to do an ng-repeat | filter on that array.

activities is my array and inside the object there is a CreatePeriod property.

```
<li ng-repeat="activity in activities track by $index | filter:{CreatePeriod:'Today'}:true">
```

The property does exist, {{activity.CreatePeriod}} displays the correct information. The CreatePeriod can be 'Today', 'Yesterday', and 'Older'.

What am I missing in my filter to only show an activity if its CreatePeriod == 'Today'

Comment: It should work..probably `track by $index` is doing something with it..could you move `track by $index` to end after filtering like `ng-repeat="activity in activities | filter:{CreatePeriod:'Today'}:true track by $index"`

Comment: @PankajParkar you were also right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`track by` must come after all filters per the docs

> Note: track by must always be the last expression:

try:

```
<li ng-repeat="activity in activities | filter:{CreatePeriod:'Today'}:true  track by $index">
```